# How to get out output of a html into textarea using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, textarea

I am developing a tool which send emails using exchange.
I have a classic asp page which has a textarea and a textbox control.

In the textbox control user will input ORDER NO. On the getfocus event of textarea, textarea should get the content. The content I want to fill is from a HTML page which is order acknowledgement which user sends to the customer.

I am able to fill single line but not the whole order acknowledgement report into the textarea.

I need to know how to do this usig AJAX.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function getrpt()
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var flname=this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML=flname;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open('GET','SalesOrder.asp',true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="" onclick="return getrpt();">get</a>

<textarea name="emBody" rows="10" COLS="55" id="txtarea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show what you have already?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by "I am able to fill single line"?

Comment: if i execute document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML='some text here' this code will execute without any error message. But I need whole html content from the salesorder.asp into the textarea which is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean the salesorder.asp html content doesn't get filled on get link click.